# Apache camel route with rabbit MQ returns "because of No endpoint could be found for"

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, apache-camel

I have tried to implement a simple application with Apache Camel and RabbitMQ. Below is the route that I have:

```
from("direct:startQueuePoint")
        .id("idOfQueueHere")
        .marshal(jsonDataFormat)
        .to("rabbitmq:tasks?hostname=localhost&port=5672&autoDelete=false&routingKey=camel")
        .end();
```

When I run the spring boot application which runs this route, it throws an error:

*because of No endpoint could be found for: rabbitmq://tasks?autoDelete=false&hostname=localhost&port=5672&routingKey=camel, please check your classpath contains the needed Camel component jar*

I created an exchange by name 'tasks' in RabbitMQ management console and binded it to the queue 'task_queue' with the routing key 'camel'. I could see in the netstat that the port 5672 is running the erlang exe.

I am not sure what mistake I am making here. Could someone please help me out here?

Comment: Obvious question: are you sure the "camel-rabbitmq" dependency is in your classpath ?

Comment: I got my thinking into incorrect direction after seeing the error of no endpoint found. After adding the proper dependency in pom.xml, this issue is resolved. Thank you.